# Run python scripts (different python verions) with one C program

Tags: python, c++, c, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to run a few python scripts in threads with a small C/++ program, but I need different python versions to run these scripts, because the package MySQLdb isn't working in python3 and some packages aren't available in python2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include <python3/Python.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* file;

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    file = fopen("myscript.py","r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "myscript.py");
    Py_Finalize();

    return;
}
```

Or via

```
system ("python2.7 myscript1.py arg1 arg2");
system ("python3 myscript2.py arg1 arg2");
```

Do you have any ideas or another way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system()` call to execute your python scripts, but there is no need of specifying the version of python executable on the command line.

You can use shebang.

Use `#!/usr/bin/python3` as the very first line for scripts that you want to run with `python3` and `#!/usr/bin/python2` in scripts that you want to run with python2.

If you are working on windows then please have a look at [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)